# Gradients in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: css, background, internet-explorer-9, gradient

Does anyone know the vendor prefix for gradients within IE9 or are we still supposed to still be using their proprietry filters?

What I've got for the other browsers is:

```
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* FF3.6 */
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #444444),color-stop(1, #999999)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#444444', EndColorStr='#999999'); /* IE6,IE7 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#444444', EndColorStr='#999999')"; /* IE8 */
```

As a bonus does anyone know Opera's vendor prefix as well?

Comment: Even though I've selected an answer - this is only relevant at this point in time.  If this changes, can someone update the thread?  Much appreciated.

Comment: Totally. I doubt IE 9 will implement gradients now though, as it’s in beta.

Comment: IE9 does not support gradients but IE10 will.

Comment: IE is just a horrible browser all together, doesn't support inline blocks, position values break for no reason, no gradient support, slow as all hell...  Let's all start warning users that they need to stop using IE instead of wasting our time supporting a sub standard browser.  Personally I have been outright stopping IE users from viewing any of my pages for years now (direct them to get a real browser) and I have never lost a sale.  Do some research and you'll see IE accounts for < 5% of all internet traffic and < 1% of sales.  Why are we supporting it?

Comment: Dan, I'd be interested as to where your numbers are coming from, I can't find a single source stating that IE is <5% of traffic.

Comment: Jamie, a common mistake developers make is they view the visitor statistics on their own programming/web-dev related website and apply those stats to the web as a whole. IE is by far the most used web browser and it's depressing how many people still use IE 8 and 9.

Comment: @Gavin - actually, by [most accounts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers) Chrome pulled even with IE some time in 2012 and is now by far the dominant browser (both desktop and mobile). But yes, IE is still far from <5% of traffic.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You still need to use their proprietary filters as of IE9 beta 1.

Comment: According to http://css3please.com, IE10 looks due to support CSS gradients, which is good news...

Comment: css3please.com helped me find a solution to mine. Thanks

Answer (score 58):

Looks like I'm a little late to the party, but here's an example for some of the top browsers:

```css
/* IE10 */ 
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #444444 0%, #999999 100%);

/* Mozilla Firefox */ 
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444444 0%, #999999 100%);

/* Opera */ 
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #444444 0%, #999999 100%);

/* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #444444), color-stop(1, #999999));

/* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #444444 0%, #999999 100%);

/* Proposed W3C Markup */ 
background-image: linear-gradient(top, #444444 0%, #999999 100%);
```

Source: http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/CSSGradientBackgroundMaker/Default.html

Note: all of these browsers also support rgb/rgba in place of hexadecimal notation.

Comment: I wouldn't consider IE10 to be a major browser yet.

Comment: @DavidMurdoch that's techincally true, but it doesn't make sense not to add the proprietory exension to your CSS, since we know what it will be. After all, IE10 is destined to become a major browser.

Comment: @Robotsushi although it doesn't answer the question for IE9 (the selected answer does, which is probably why it was chosen), this question is on the first page of Google results for "internet explorer css gradients," so there isn't any harm in having something useful here now that IE10 is almost ready for Windows 7.

Comment: The latest versions of Firefox and Opera support the W3C standard. (I tested on Firefox 19 and Opera 12.14 on Windows 7)

Comment: Since this is top-voted answer for the question, which addresses IE9, it should add the filter: to the end so that it includes IE9 support.

Answer (score 47):

The best cross-browser solution is

```
background: #fff;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #000);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #000);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #000);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#fff, #000);/*For IE10*/
background: linear-gradient(#fff, #000);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000000');/*For IE7-8-9*/ 
height: 1%;/*For IE7*/
```

Answer (score 37):

IE9 currently lacks CSS3 gradient support. However, here is a nice workaround solution using PHP to return an SVG (vertical linear) gradient instead, which allows us to keep our design in our stylesheets.

```
<?php

$from_stop = isset($_GET['from']) ? $_GET['from'] : '000000';
$to_stop = isset($_GET['to']) ? $_GET['to'] : '000000';

header('Content-type: image/svg+xml; charset=utf-8');

echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>
';

?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#<?php echo $from_stop; ?>" stop-opacity="1"/>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#<?php echo $to_stop; ?>" stop-opacity="1"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#linear-gradient)"/>
</svg>
```

Simply upload it to your server and call the URL like so:

```
gradient.php?from=f00&to=00f
```

This can be used in conjunction with your CSS3 gradients like this:

```
.my-color {
    background-color: #f00;
    background-image: url(gradient.php?from=f00&to=00f);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f00), to(#00f));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f00, #00f);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f00, #00f);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #f00, #00f);
}
```

If you need to target below IE9, you can still use the old proprietary 'filter' method:

```
.ie7 .my-color, .ie8 .my-color {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr="#ff0000", endColorStr="#0000ff");
}
```

Of course you can amend the PHP code to add more stops on the gradient, or make it more sophisticated (radial gradients, transparency etc.) but this is great for those simple (vertical) linear gradients.

Comment: Elegant solution.  
FYI: I just confirmed SVG is _not_ downloaded for browsers supporting `linear-gradient`.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to cache these svg files once they are created.

Comment: A more robust question would be to find out what the performance is on both time and server load for requesting a cached file vs. generating a file stream each and every time.

Comment: PHP should never have knowledge or help in your UI design. Keep the client needs on the client.

Answer (score 11):

The code I use for all browser gradients:

```css
background: #0A284B;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0A284B), to(#135887));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#0A284B, #135887);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0A284B, #135887);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#0A284B, #135887);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#0A284B, #135887);
background: linear-gradient(#0A284B, #135887);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0A284B', endColorstr='#135887');
zoom: 1;
```

You will need to specify a height or `zoom: 1` to apply `hasLayout` to the element for this to work in IE.

---

**Update:**

Here is a LESS Mixin (CSS) version for all you LESS users out there:

```css
.gradient(@start, @end) {
    background: mix(@start, @end, 50%);
    filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr="@start~", EndColorStr="@end~")";
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(@start), to(@end));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(@start, @end);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, @start, @end);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(@start, @end);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(@start, @end);
    background: linear-gradient(@start, @end);
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: As a LESS user, I was hunting around for a way to make the gradients work in IE9 as well. I found a blog article detailing how to generate the SVG:
http://blog.philipbrown.id.au/2012/09/base64-encoded-svg-gradient-backgrounds-in-less/

Answer (score 6):

Opera will soon start having builds available with gradient support, as well as other CSS features.

The W3C CSS Working Group is not even finished with CSS 2.1, y'all know that, right? We intend to be finished very soon. CSS3 is modularized precisely so we can move modules through to implementation faster rather than an entire spec.

Every browser company uses a different software cycle methodology, testing, and so on. So the process takes time.

I'm sure many, many readers well know that if you're using anything in CSS3, you're doing what's called "progressive enhancement" - the browsers with the most support get the best experience. The other part of that is "graceful degradation" meaning the experience will be agreeable but perhaps not the best or most attractive until that browser has implemented the module, or parts of the module that are relevant to what you want to do.

This creates quite an odd situation that unfortunately front-end devs get extremely frustrated by: inconsistent timing on implementations. So it's a real challenge on either side - do you blame the browser companies, the W3C, or worse yet - yourself (goodness knows we can't know it all!) Do those of us who are working for a browser company and W3C group members blame ourselves? You?

Of course not. It's always a game of balance, and as of yet, we've not as an industry figured out where that point of balance really is. That's the joy of working in evolutionary technology :)

Answer (score 4):

I understand that IE9 still won't be supporting CSS gradients. Which is a shame, because it's supporting loads of other great new stuff.

You might want to look into [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie) as a way of getting all versions of IE to support various CSS3 features (including gradients, but also border-radius and box-shadow) with the minimum of fuss.

I believe CSS3Pie works with IE9 (I've tried it on the pre-release versions, but not yet on the current beta).

Comment: Thanks Spudley.  I'm using CSS3Pie on IE6 to 8, but I was hoping to get away from using it on IE9!  I've got a separate stylesheet for each IE with my CSS3Pie styles in the IE8. As long as gradients is the only thing missing from the CSS3 I currently use, I'll be adding another stylesheet for IE9 without using CSS3Pie if I can get away with it.

Comment: I didn't even see this post, my bad. Just wrote an answer and voted to delete it with the same info. Note:
Be wary of the known issues:
http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about IE9, but Opera doesn’t seem to have any gradient support yet:

- http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto26/#css

No occurrence of “gradient” on that page.

There’s a great article by Robert Nyman on getting CSS gradients working in all browsers that aren’t Opera though:

- http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/15/css-gradients-for-all-web-browsers-without-using-images/

Not sure if that can be extended to use an image as a fallback.

Comment: That surprises me, as Opera are usually at the forefront of implementing the standards.  Thanks for the answer Paul.

Comment: I don’t think gradients have made it into a standard yet though. As I understand the process, new CSS features tend to be implemented in a browser, then eventually specified in a standard. I believe the WebKit team first implemented gradients in CSS (unless you count Microsoft and their `filter` stuff, which doesn’t really qualify as CSS in my book). Firefox have now followed them, but there doesn’t seem to be anything in a W3C CSS draft spec yet: see http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=gradient+site:www.w3.org

Answer (score 2):

As of version 11, Opera supports linear gradients with the -o- vendor prefix. Chris Mills wrote a Dev.Opera article about it: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-linear-gradients/

Radial gradients are still in the works (both in the spec, and within Opera).

Answer (score 1):

Use an Gradient Generator - and everything will be perfect ;)
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/