# CSS3 Linear gradients and Opera?

Tags: css, opera

Does Opera browser supports linear-gradient? What is syntax?
Thanks

Comment: Opera 12.10 supports unprefixed CSS3 gradients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Oper does not support linear gradient of CSS3. But, you can use `svg` for backgrounds. Here is content of simple svg file with gradient:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100%">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: #9c0000;"/>
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: #590000;"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>

    <rect x="0" y="0" fill="url(#gradient)" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, but it has been announced that it will very soon. My guess would be March.

Answer (score 1):

AS of Aug 2011 **YES**, Opera does support linear gradients.

At [Gradients in Internet Explorer 9](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3934693/881286) you can see the how using it.

Briefly:

```
/* Opera */ 
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #444444 0%, #999999 100%);
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

**No but here's the best solution**.

Go to photoshop, make a big ass gradient in whatever direction lets say 2560px x 20px

Use "save for website" as a jpg, using and any % of quality but save it as 2560px x 1px instead.

Use it as a background image with repeat-x or repeat-y whatever repeat is required to extend the 1px width/height....And it will barely cost you a KiloByte or two.