# what is the replacement for filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient

Tags: css, web

I'm using the following in my CSS (CSS3) file in order to create a gradient in Internet Explorer:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient
```

for example

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#C4D5FB', endColorstr='#DAE6FB'); /* for IE */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#C4D5FB), to(#DAE6FB)); /* for webkit browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #C4D5FB,  #DAE6FB); /* for firefox 3.6+ */
```

I have just read that it is deprecated since Internet Explorer 9 but still works.
Is it safe to use it? is there a replacement for it?

according to:
[internet-explorer-9-gradients-with-rounded-corners](http://abouthalf.com/2010/10/25/internet-explorer-9-gradients-with-rounded-corners/)

it is safe to use it:

> Tools like the Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator generate the code needed for lovely CSS3 gradients with a fallback option for legacy Internet Explorer (using the gradient filter mentioned above).

thank you.

Comment: possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934693/gradients-in-internet-explorer-9 ?

Comment: I was not able to understand if it is risky to keep working with the filter. should I work with images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This site

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Check the IE9 Support box. It will give you an SVG solution.

Comment: the issue with SVG is that I need to add if-else statement for every Element with gradient:         <!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .gradient {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->

Comment: For further reading, and interesting bit about which prefixes are worthy of including:
http://lea.verou.me/2013/04/can-we-get-rid-of-gradient-prefixes/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the inset for box-shadow to by pass the gradient. I had this problem and just could not get it to work. So I saw this article http://www.sitepoint.com/shadow-boxing-image-free-css3-glossy-buttons/. Worked great for me.

This is the code I used on my project.

```
border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius:5px;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), inset 0px 5px 12px #930, inset 0px 15px 2px rgba(240, 150, 69, .5),inset 0px 25px 25px #930;
```