# Background image gradient not working with ie9

Tags: html, css

Seems that the below code doesn't work with ie9. Is there a workaround?
Thanks

```
.orangeback {
/* IE10 Consumer Preview */ 
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FF6900 0%, #FF8214 100%);

/* Mozilla Firefox */ 
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FF6900 0%, #FF8214 100%);

/* Opera */ 
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FF6900 0%, #FF8214 100%);

/* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #FF6900), color-stop(1, #FF8214));

/* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FF6900 0%, #FF8214 100%);

/* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */ 
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FF6900 0%, #FF8214 100%);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gradients in Internet Explorer 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934693/gradients-in-internet-explorer-9)

Comment: IE9 doesn't support gradients. You would need to use a Filter, but really ask yourself if it's the end of the world if outdated browsers don't get gradients... Chances are, it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty close:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ff6900', endColorstr='#ff8214',GradientType=0 );
```

This works in IE6+.

Or, for JUST IE9, you can replace it with an SVG by using the following styles, if the `filter` option doesn't float your boat:

Add to `.orangeback`:

```
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
```

Also add `.ie9-gradient` class to these elements, and add the following before the closing `head` tag:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .ie9-gradient {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

To use the SVG polyfill for CSS3 gradients in IE9 you need to disable filter, so this code retains the `filter` gradient fallback for IE6-8 and uses SVG for IE9.

In your case, there is not really a need to use the SVG polyfill for IE9 because you are using a normal 2 color linear gradient.  If you had a more complex gradient the second solution would probably be preferable, but for your purposes just using the `filter` solution should work fine.

Use this (or a CSS preprocessor) and never worry about CSS3 gradients again: [Colorzilla Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Comment: I was about to suggest Colorzilla as well.  I use it all the time. [http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000000');/*For IE7-8-9*/
```

Let me know if it works.