# Why does this button appear blue in IE9?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-9

I have specified in my class `.btnDeleteCostEstimate button` to override the default background.  In Chrome, it appears correctly as light gray.  However, in IE9, it appears as a dark blue.

It looks like the color is coming from the `.BPMButton` class by the following property:

```
background-color: rgb(27, 117, 188)
```

Can anyone tell me what I can do to make the button appear in IE9 the same way it appears in Chrome?

Here is my jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/8DL3q/

Here is screenshot, as you can see, there is a dark blue gradient effect in IE9 whereas the expected gradient would be light grey (as shown in Chrome):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, I was specifying my colors as:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #555 0%, #999 100%);
```

Which, IE9 interprets as this:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #000555 0%, #000999 100%);
```

Whereas, Google Chrome interprets it as this (correctly):

```
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #555555 0%, #999999 100%);
```

So, to fix it, I just had to change to this and it works in both browsers:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #555555 0%, #999999 100%);
```

Here is the example that now works in both browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/8DL3q/11/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the background colour (line 4) to another colour.
(change `background-color: #1b75bc;`).
There is nowhere else in the code where that colour (#1B75BC) is referenced.

<strike>On line 25 you have 
`background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #124B80 0%, #1B76BC 100%);`

IE9 doesn't support gradients: ([Gradients in Internet Explorer 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934693/gradients-in-internet-explorer-9))</strike>

Comment: Thanks but if I remove that line it doesn't seem to change anything.  The button is still blue.  If I change it to another color, there is still no effect.

Comment: What colour blue is it exactly? (In hex).

Comment: You can see it in IE9 if you open it.  The actual color appears to be 1B75BC i.e. rgb(27, 117, 188).

Comment: As a fallback, it should use the `background-color` property from line #4, but it doesn't appear to be respecting that.  How can I get it to fallback to grey on fail (and not the dark blue)?

Comment: It is definitely the background colour from what I can see. There's nothing else in the code referencing #1B75BC. Try Ctrl+F5?

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle to use the proper background color (#999), but there seems to be no effect http://jsfiddle.net/8DL3q/9/ Any idea how to make the background grey in IE?

Comment: Alas not sorry =/
I've got to shoot off somewhere. I hope you manage to find an answer! :D

Answer (score 0):

Because IE9 doesn't support CSS Gradients - see [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=gradients). If you want to use gradients you you can use [colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Comment: colorzilla actually helped me find my answer.  Once I entered #555 I realized it was converting it to #000555 which is exactly what IE9 was doing.  To fix it, I just specified the full hexadecimal value #555555 (as per my answer below).  Thanks for your help.