# Linear Gradients not working in internet explorer 9 and filter: progid: is not working

Tags: css

This has been asked a few times but they are a few years old and I was wondering if there has been a better way in solving this issue. The below css:

```
.defaultButton {
  background: #90c8eb;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #90c8eb, #0b85d1);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #90c8eb, #0b85d1);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #90c8eb, #0b85d1);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #90c8eb, #0b85d1);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #90c8eb, #0b85d1);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5;
  -moz-border-radius: 5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 0.800em;
  font-weight: none;
  padding: 7px 14px 7px 16px;
  border: solid #6f92a8 1px;

}
```

`linear-gradient` works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari but doesn't work in IE 9. I found a few css hack site but they didn't work. One mentioned doing:

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #90c8eb/9, #0b85d1/9);
```

Adding `/9` did not work nor did `\0/`. Not sure if I used them wrong but so far I have been unsuccessful in getting this to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradients in Internet Explorer 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934693/gradients-in-internet-explorer-9)

Comment: If you check the dupe link you'll find how to make it work using SVG

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#90c8eb', endColorstr='#0b85d1', GradientType=0);
```

Comment: I just did and it did not work... Thank you for your efforts.