# Css background arrow percentage width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a box with a "cool" looking triangle background (covers 50% of the box). I solved for any fixed width but forgot that on mobile the width is not fixed anymore, making my solutions to fail on mobile devices.

To create the background, I use border technique setting each side of the border to half of the height/width, but, borders cant be in percentage (%).

How can I possibly achieve that?

Below is my code:

```
.outer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px
}
.background-triangle {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-right: 250px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1); /* half width */
    border-bottom: 150px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);/*half height*/
    border-left: 250px solid transparent;/*half width*/
    border-top: 150px solid transparent; /* half height*/
}

.box-color {
  position: relative; 
  background-color: #6699cc;
}
```

and a very straightforward html

```
<div class="outer">
    <a href="/#">
        <div class="box-color" style="">
            <div class="background-triangle"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I would prefer a non-javascript option if possbile. I guess I could set the width when the window size changes.

Edit: What I want to achieve is to make the black background triangle stretch the full width of its containing element. Try resizing the jsfiddle window and see how the triangle has a fixed width. It does not follow the containing "blueish" box width change. I hope this clears the question up.

[And a jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/kmmg9L01/3/)

Comment: What do you wish to achieve exactly?

Comment: Do you mean you want a right-angled triangle inside the box (rectangle), with responsiveness on mobile devises?

Comment: I do not fully understand you're question but if you are looking for a alternative for % you can use something like em

Comment: added an "edit" for better explanation of the question.

Comment: Probably easier to achieve using a background gradient, instead of the border triangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use linear background instead of traditional triangle generation technique. Check this solution at this updated jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ashekthegreat/kmmg9L01/6/

```
.background-triangle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 50%)
}
```

Comment: This seem to work just as I wanted it thanks. Is there a fix for ie9 (a nice-to-have feature but not required)

Comment: This post may help you: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934693/gradients-in-internet-explorer-9